# How to web scrap all the urls present in excel file in one go

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have a file **Input.xlsx** which contains 130 ursls links, I want to Scrap all the links at once,
and extract them in a text file with their **URL_ID** as its file name.

I am a beginner in web scraping, so I need stack overflow community support and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the excel as a zip. Find all the .xml.rels (.\xl\worksheets\_rels). You want all of the "Target" attribute values inside of the Relationship tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
   <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="https://www.theregister.co.uk/" TargetMode="External"/>
</Relationships>
```